# How to reference an external function in nuxt.config?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

So basically I'm setting up an app using nuxt, and within the configuration's `generate` property I need to run a recursive function to build the sites route tree dynamically. The function is rather large so I dont want it to be in the config file itself

Ive tried doing it this way, but think Im way off

```js
import {buildChildRoutes} from 'routeGenerator'

export default {
  generate: {
    routes(){
      var response = await this.$deliveryClient
      .itemsFeedAll()                  
      .toPromise();

      return buildChildRoutes(response)
    })
```

has anyone done something like this before? i would assume its common and im just missing something in the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I used that works

This is my code in `nuxt.config.js`

```js
import getRoutes from './utils/route-generator.js'

const dynamicRoutes = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(getRoutes())
  })
}

export default {
  generate: {
    routes: dynamicRoutes
  }
}
```